# How do I use "If statement" in echo function for PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

For example, I would like to print total classes in the school

If.. that course has only one class, it will print "Total 1 Class"
but if there are many classes in that course, it will print "Total 15 Classes"

So, I want to use syntax like

```
<?php echo "Total ".$attendance_setting->class_number.  
 if($attendance_setting->class_number==1) {echo " Class";} else {echo "
 Classes";} ?>
```

Is it possible or I have to use If statement before I print it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a ternary operation for this:

```
echo "Total " . $attendance_setting->class_number . " ";
echo ($attendance_setting->class_number > 0)
     ? echo "Classes"
     : echo "Class";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
echo class_number.($attendance_setting->class_number==1)?'class':'classes';
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally define a function like this.

```
function add_plural_s($int=0){
    return $int > 1 ? 's' : '';
}
```

I then write as follows:

```
echo 'Class'.add_plural_s($attendance_setting->class_number);
```

This prints `Class` if not supposed to be plural and `Classs` if supposed to be plural.

However I have just realized that in your case in it will not work like I have defined the function  because you need more then just an `s`. But you get the idea anyway.

Comment: I guess you could extend the function with a second parameter specifying a 'pre-s' string in case of pluralizing

Comment: thanks for your suggession, this's very useful and I'll adapt to use in other opportunities.

Comment: @mek its a pleasure, by the way if you like an answer you should vote it up. Oh, you havent yet reached the minimum voting rep? Thats easily fixed with a vote to your interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just perform the if statements prior to echo-ing the statement, something like the following:

```
<?php 

if($attendance_setting->class_number==1) {
    $class = " Class";
}
else {
    $class = " Classes";
} 

echo "Total " . $attendance_setting->class_number . $class;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use switch() statement