# PHP if shorthand and echo in one line - possible?

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, shorthand

What's the best, preferred way of writing if shorthand one-liner such as:

```
expression ? $foo : $bar
```

Plot twist: I need to `echo $foo` or `echo $bar`. Any crazy tricks? :)

Comment: *Ternary statement*, not *shorthand if*. What's the actual question here?

Comment: echo expression ? $foo : $bar;

Comment: @Phil: *Conditional expression*, not *ternary statement*.  :)  Were it a statement, `echo` would work in the branches.  And the only reason you can get away with calling it the ternary anything is that there's currently only one ternary operator.  "Ternary" meaning having to do with three, though...it's not a very helpful name.  :)

Comment: @cHao Ah yes, `s/statement/operator`. It just bothers me when I hear *shorthand if*

Comment: Nowadays we have the elvis '??' operator https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993455/560287

Comment: another dupe: [How do I use "If statement" in echo function for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12182940/2943403)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
<?=(expression) ? $foo : $bar?>
```

edit: [here's a good read for you on the topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php)

edit: [more to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188397/why-are-echo-short-tags-permanently-enabled-as-of-php-5-4)

Comment: The parentheses are redundant

Comment: I've never seen PHP fail to evaluate the conditional expression, no matter how complex, sans a pair of wrapping parentheses

Comment: Don't mind me, I'm just a stickler for unnecessary syntax (like using parentheses in ternaries and `include` / `require` statements)

Comment: If you're in the habit of using `and` and `or` in your conditions rather than `&&` and `||`, it can trip you up.  But only because the wordy operators have different precedence.

Comment: what can i do if I want to echo only when true and do nothing on false?

Comment: $bar = '' @pavitran

Comment: Short-tags are disabled by default and are depreciated and it's advice to NOT use this any longer. 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @danger89 <?= isn't deprecated... in 5.4 on that very page you linked 'The tag <?= is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting.'

Comment: @Adam Indeed, but that is only for version 5.4. Otherwise there is stated: `<? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini `

Comment: @danger89 it is from 5.4 onwards. <? is discouraged since it relies on short_open_tag being enabled as you said. <?= even in 7.X doesn't rely on this option being enabled therefore there is no reason for it to be discouraged.

Answer (score 12):

```
echo (expression) ? $foo : $bar;
```

Answer (score 7):

The [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) evaluates to the value of the second expression if the first one evaluates to `TRUE`, and evaluates to the third expression if the first evaluates to `FALSE`. To `echo` one value or the other, just pass the ternary expression to the `echo` statement.

```
echo expression ? $foo : $bar;
```

Read more about the ternary operator in the PHP manual for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 0):

Great answers above, and I love when programmers ask questions like this to create clear, concise and clinical coding practices. For anyone that might find this useful:

```
<?php

// grabbing the value from a function, this is just an example
$value = function_to_return_value(); // returns value || FALSE

// the following structures an output if $value is not FALSE
echo ( !$value ? '' : '<div>'. $value .'</div>' ); 

// the following will echo $value if exists, and nothing if not
echo $value ?: '';
// OR (same thing as)
echo ( $value ?: '' ); 

// or null coalesce operator
echo $value ?? '';
// OR (same thing as)
echo ( $value ?? '' );

?>
```

*References:*

- [PHP Operators Comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
- [Null Coalesce Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

Answer (score -1):

```
   // check if it value is true then display value otherwise it display empty or ''
    <?= $color ? $color : ''; ?>
   // same thing if condition is true then display Condition is true otherwise display Condition is false
    <?php echo $condition ? 'Condition is true' : 'Condition is false';?>
```