# if/else shorthand to define a variable

Tags: php

I have troubles understanding how the php shorthands for if/else described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233207/php-if-shorthand-and-echo-in-one-line-possible) works.

```
<?=(expression) ? $foo : $bar?>
```

The expression I'm trying to shorten is the following :

```
if (isset($result[1][0])) {
    $var = $result[1][0];
} else {
    $var = "";
}
```

Can somebody explain me how I can apply the shorthand if/else statement in my situation ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ternary operator like this:

```
$var = (isset($result[1][0])) ? $result[1][0] : "";
```

> See more about [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

In case of PHP 7, you can do it like this:

```
$var = $result[1][0] ?? ''
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe add a closing parenthesis ?

Comment: PHP 7 can even make it shorter: $var = $result[1][0] ?? "";

Comment: Thank you for all theses quick answers, I wasn't even close... Unfortunately I'm not running PHP 7 at the moment so I'll go with this :) Thanks !

Comment: The parentheses around the `isset` expression aren't really necessary. It doesn't hurt to have them, but you don't need them.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - Yes the parenthesis isn't necessary but the code seems clean and understandable by using that parenthesis. So I prefer to use that parenthesis!

Comment: I understand. I didn't intend to be critical. Just thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Think of it as:

Condition **?** Executes if condition is true **:** otherwise

In your case:

```
$var = isset($result[1][0]) ? $result[1][0] : "";
```

condition: `isset($result[1][0])`

if true: `return $result[1][0]`

else: `return ""`